# How to gracefully shutdown a service?

Tags: android, service, background, shutdown, foreground

I am developing an app that starts a service to get GPS coordinates. But after changing the java code and then when I install a newer version of my app I want to gracefully shutdown the running service. (Currently I believe the installation simply crashes the running service)

How do I shutdown the service gracefully?

Comment: When you uninstall the app (or force stop from the settings), the process gets killed immediately without any framework callbacks. You just need to persist any data you need at reasonable intervals so not much is lost.

Comment: @Pawel I thought Android keeps pretty good control over its app lifecycles, I would be surprised if it did not at least attempt a graceful cleanup (e.g., `Service.onDestroy()`) of the app before killing the process. Any references to back that up?

Comment: my service onDestroy() is never called.

Comment: I withdraw my comment; I just checked some of my old app logs, and it does appear that @Pawel is correct; `onDestroy()` is not called.